# Pymongo db insert not reflecting in the mongo database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using the following Python code to update a DB named 'mc' and a collection named 'mc'.The code picks a csv file converts the record to json and inserts into db.

The code is running without any error or warnings ,but when i look into the data base from a command prompt using `db.collections.find()` i am not able to find the inserted documents there.I strongly believe i am missing some kind of commit operation here.

```
import  pymongo
import json,os
import pandas as pd

class DbHelper(object):
    dbname = ''
    def import_content(self):
        mng_client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        mng_db = mng_client['mc'] # Replace mongo db name
        mng_db.authenticate('XXXXX', 'XXXXXX',mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1'))
        collection_name = 'mc' # Replace mongo db collection name
        db_cm = mng_db[collection_name]
        file_res = "D:\\File\\MC\\Test_Nukes\\ParsedCSVData.csv"
        data = pd.read_csv(file_res)
        data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
        print data_json
        db_cm.insert(data_json)
        mng_client.close()
d = DbHelper()
d.import_content()
```

Comment: Are you inserting all json documents in one shot? Then you will have to use bulkinsert.. I'm not sure about pymongo. In java it can be done using bulkinsert or insertMany option which allows to insert multiple documents in one shot..

Comment: the csv file contains only one row ,so only one json record is being inserted here

Comment: its not throwing any error? If not, its strange! Its better you can print the document before and after insertion by using find() operation. I'm not aware how this can be done in pymongo.. I'm sorry for the earlier guess!

Comment: np :) .I tried that and its fine on that side.